# Use of Autoclosure

Tags: swift

[image]

I found this example on https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/using-autoclosure-when-designing-swift-apis
I am little confuse between use of `autoclosure` and delaying operation. I want to know what will happen if I remove `@autoclosure` from this example. I know then curly braces required but other than that? Everywhere explanation is expression will get evaluated only after you call it. But every function will get evaluated when we call it. so How `autoclosure` helping it to delaying. Or just we get syntactic relaxation of not required to put curly braces around expression

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=4

Answer (score 1):

> Or just we get syntactic relaxation of not required to put curly braces around expression

Exactly. It also *hides* the delayed evaluation from the caller.
Another example are the “short-circuiting” logical operators `||` and `&&`, for example

```
public static func ||(lhs: Bool, rhs: @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

so that in

```
let b = functionReturningBool() || otherFunctionReturningBool()
```

the second function is not called if the first one already returned
`true`.

Comment: I am not that experienced guy to understand short-circuiting. I just started to learn and trying to understand what idea behind it. Just tell me one thing even from your example if I remove @autoclosure then what will happen? Code will work exactly the same with normal closure right?

Comment: @Tanzz: Yes, but it had to be called as `functionReturningBool() || { otherFunctionReturningBool() }`

Comment: Yeah that I get it. So functionally delaying something is depend on our logical statement right. @autoclosure is just for removing curly braces and create code easy to understand & read.

Comment: and there is another one difference between normal closure and  @autoclosure. `@autoclosure`  doesn’t take any arguments as mentioned in swift documentation.

Comment: @Tanzz You're correcct. Closures are used to store a bit of code for later `execution`. In your example, `errorExpression` is a closure that can be later evaluated to return an error object. But if the optional is not `nil`, then no error object is needed, so the program doesn't need to waste any time generating it. Autoclosure is used to make this process look nicer. `a || (b && c)` looks a lot nicer than `a || { (b && { c } ) }`

Comment: @alexander Thats my point. `@autoclosure` is attribute which needed to write expression without curly braces. Why they are just saying autoclosure making code delayed. Without attribute that is also a normal closure. Sometimes everyone make you confuse about single idea by using different names to them. Because in that example guard statement taking care of if that closure need to be evaluated or not. `@autoclosure` attribute making it nicer to write. Instead of calling it closure with @autoclosure attribute everyone just saying `An autoclosure lets you delay evaluation` like in documentation.